# How algebraic is the holonomy map?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, connections, holonomy, ind-schemes

Let $G$ be either a compact, simple, simply-connected Lie group, or a simply-connected complex reductive group (so either $SU(n)$ or $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, for instance), or even complex affine. I don't know the correct setting for this question, so assume the case that makes it work. Please bear with the tentativeness of this question.

Consider the space $\mathcal{A}$ of polynomial or Laurent connections (again, take the option that works or makes sense) on the trivial $G$-bundle on $\mathbb{C}^\times$. This is something like an ind-scheme (perhaps only in the reductive case, and possibly only after picking a faithful representation). In the case of *smooth* connections on $G\times S^1$ (and probably for analytic too) we have a holonomy map $\mathcal{A}^{sm} \to G$, and this is a surjective submersion. I *think* there is also such a map for the case of $\mathcal{A}$, going around $S^1\subset \mathbb{C}^\times$.

> In the event this exists, how algebraic is this map? Is it surjective?

My thought is that this may be a cover in some generalised sense. Maps from ind-schemes to schemes aren't so common, though that I know how to find how they work or what they do. There are some [notes by Gaitsgory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/Nantes14/InfSchtext.pdf) that don't help me at all.

Comment: I don't know the general answer, but would guess no.  Think about the connection on $\mathbb{C}^\times$ with covariant derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-a/x$.  This has holonomy around the circle given by $e^a$, which is about as transcendental as it gets.  In general, anything that involves solving a differential equation (as holonomy does) is really bad news for staying algebraic.

Comment: Hmm, I should throw log-algebraic into the mix as well, now you mention it. Not sure that fixes the example you mention, though... (which I don't quite understand: is G=C^×?)

Comment: @BenWebster that's doesn't look like a polynomial connection, though... :-) (perhaps it is: this is pushing at the boundaries of where I can make sense of the geometry.)

Comment: It's a Laurent polynomial connection!  You're right that it doesn't completely kill things, but it was meant as an illustration of how "solve a differential equation" is an extremely non-polynomial operation.

Comment: @BenWebster Note that a map of ind-schemes $\mathcal{A} \to G$ lives in the set $\lim_{i\in I}Sch(\mathcal{A}_i,G)$, where $\mathcal{A} = colim_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$ in the category of ind-schemes and each $\mathcal{A}_i$ is a scheme. I may be wrong, but the exponential function is quite possibly an element of this set (I think one can take $I=\mathbb{N}$, and the $n^{th}$ coordinate as the $n^{th}$ Taylor polynomial of exp)

Comment: @DavidRoberts You can't, because there is a consistency condition The weird definition of ind-schemes map doesn't help you construct any new maps from a fixed subscheme of the ind-scheme.

Comment: @WillSawin ah, I see! How obvious... I'm still interested in the properties of the given map, though.

Answer (score 4):

Connections on the trivial $G$-bundle can be identified with maps from the base to $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ via $x\frac{d}{dx} + f(x) \leftrightarrow f(x)$.  One way to present this as an ind-scheme is by choosing generators of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Lie}(G)}$, and considering the finite dimensional affine space of ring maps $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Lie}(G)} \to \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ for which the generators land in $\bigoplus_{n=-N}^N \mathbb{C} x^n$.

Following Ben Webster's example in the comments, consider the tangent field $x \frac{d}{dx} - a$ for $a \in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$.  This connection lies in the very first affine space of our sequence, with $N=0$.  If $a$ is semisimple, then solutions to the equation $x\frac{df}{dx} = af$ look like "$cx^a$".  The holonomy with respect to the basepoint $1$ is exponential in $a$ - in the one-dimensional case, identifying $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ with $\mathbb{C}$, we get $e^{2 \pi i a}$.

In general, this example gives us an exponential map from $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ to $G$.  This (and more generally, the holonomy map) exists in the category of (ind) complex analytic spaces, but outside the case of unipotent groups it is not algebraic.

Comment: Thanks for finally disabusing me of a vague hope! I guess, then, one can see that (for Lie groups of the sort I mention) the holonomy map is surjective. I would hope that this is some sort of submersion, regardless of its non-algebraic nature.

Comment: @David Roberts: I think the holonomy map is almost never a submersion. The exponential map is not an open map, even for compact Lie groups e.g. $SU(2)$, (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups), and not surjective in general for noncompact Lie groups (e.g. $SL_2(\mathbb C)$).

Comment: @SamGunningham in the smooth case it is! Namely, $\mathcal{A}^{sm} \to G$ is a surjective submersion for a Milnor regular Lie group (infinite-dimensional even!). I took Scott's use of the exponential map to be merely illustrating what holonomy looks like on a particular subspace of $\mathcal{A}$.